# Does working of increment and decrement operator change if used with logical operators

Tags: c, clang, output, operators, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int a = -10, b = 3, c = 0, d;
   d = a++ || ++b && c++;
   printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, ", a, b, c, d);
   a = -10, b = 3, c = 0;
   d = c++ && ++b || a++;
   printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", a, b, c, d);
   return 0;
}
```

Why is this program returning output as

-9, 3, 0, 1, -9, 3, 1, 1

Why b and c variable not incrementing as intended to?

Please explain in detail with sources for further reference.

Comment: No, but logical operations don't work exactly like you think they do. Its called "short circuit evaluation". Not all the operands/expressions are necessarily evaluated. It is guaranteed that they are not evaluated once the truth value of the overall expression is determined.

Comment: The answer is not to use statements which have side-effects in a compound conditional test.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please elaborate on what is compound conditional test, what are its side effects and which statements generate those side effects.

Comment: @FreeDragon - The "compound" part is about "doing everything at once", and just causes confusion. So just do the computations first, and then check/display the results afterwards. And please use semicolons, and not commas, to separate expressions.

Comment: @FreeDragon by 'compound' I meant "containing more than one conditional test". Side effects are statements that do other things besides the evaluation, such as `++` or calling a function which itself changes something.

Answer (score 2):

The logical operators `||` and `&&` have short-circuit behavior, which basically means that if the result of the operator can be determined by evaluating just the left operand then the right operand won't be evaluated.

First, let's look at this expression:

```
d = a++ || ++b && c++;
```

Since `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, this is the same as:

```
d = (a++ || (++b && c++));
```

So first we have the `||` operator, whose left operand is `a++`.  This evaluated to the current value of `a` which is -10, and because this value is non-zero then the result of `||` will be 1 so the right side of `||` which is `++b && c++` is not evaluated, and `b` and `c` will not be incremented.

So the end result is that `a` is incremented while `b` and `c` are not.

If we then look at this:

```
d = c++ && ++b || a++;
```

Which is the same as this:

```
d = ((c++ && ++b) || a++);
```

The left side of `||` is `c++ && ++b` which is evaluated first.  Then the left side of `&&` is `c++` which is the current value of `c` which is 0.  And since the left side of `&&` is 0, its result is 0 so the right side which is `b++` which is not evaluated.  So now we have that the left side of `||` evaluates to 0, so the right side which is `a++` is evaluated, resulting in `a` being incremented.

So the result of the above is that `a` and `c` are incremented while `b` is not.

Comment: But isn't increment have higher priority than logical operators so pre-increment should apply first before applying the logical operator. and post-increment should apply after solving the full expression whatever the result of the expression.

Comment: @FreeDragon - No, higher priority is different from evaluation order. Even if C has [15 levels of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) it doesn't mean that the compiler goes over an expression 15 times, doing each operator type separately.

Answer (score 1):

increments and decrements are not processed if condition is satisfied

https://gnu-c-language-manual.github.io/GNU-C-Language-Manual/Logical-Operators.html